# Can't access memory map from child process (Python 3.8)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, memory-mapped-files

I'm writing a program that uses Python's `multiprocessing` module to speed up CPU-bound tasks, and I want the child processes I create to access a memory map that initially gets created in the parent process without duplicating it. According to the [`multiprocessing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods), child processes no longer inherit file descriptors by default as of Python 3.4, so I've tried using `os.set_inheritable()` to override that behavior.

Here's a quick mockup I made to demonstrate the issue:

```py
DATA = r"data.csv"

from sys import platform
WINDOWS = platform.startswith("win")
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
import mmap
from typing import Optional

def child(fd: int, shm_tag: Optional[str]) -> None:
    if shm_tag: # i.e. if using Windows
        mm = mmap.mmap(fd, 0, shm_tag, mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    else:
        mm = mmap.mmap(fd, 0, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ)

    mm.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Some code differs on Windows
    WINDOWS = platform.startswith("win")

    # Open file
    fd = os.open(DATA, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_BINARY if WINDOWS else os.O_RDONLY)
    os.set_inheritable(fd, True)
    # Create memory map from file descriptor
    if WINDOWS:
        shm_tag = "shm_mmap"
        mm = mmap.mmap(fd, 0, shm_tag, mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    else:
        shm_tag = None
        mm = mmap.mmap(fd, 0, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ)

    # Run child process
    (p := Process(target = child, args = (fd, shm_tag), daemon = True)).start()
    p.join()
    p.close()

    mm.close()
    os.close(fd)
```

This hasn't been working at all—or at least not on Windows*, where I'm primarily testing. I'm receiving an error in the child process that heavily implies that the file descriptor wasn't actually inherited:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[N.D.]\Documents\test.py", line 12, in child
    mm = mmap.mmap(fd, 0, shm_tag, mmap.ACCESS_READ)
ValueError: cannot mmap an empty file
```

Furthermore, I'm getting the exact same error regardless of whether I pass `True` or `False` to `os.set_inheritable()`, as if it doesn't actually make a difference after all.

What's going on? Am I using the `mmap` module incorrectly?

* *Possibly relevant: Windows uses `spawn()` to create new processes rather than `fork()`, and throws an exception if you try to memory map an empty file.*

Comment: `multiprocessing` spawns worker processes via `subprocess.Popen` without inheriting handles. It relies on explicit duplication of handles. Even if it did inherit *handles*, subprocess doesn't use the private CRT protocol to inherit C *file descriptors*. You'd have to pass the handle from `msvcrt.get_osfhandle`, and then in the child wrap it in a file descriptor via `msvcrt.open_osfhandle`.

Comment: A workaround, since you're naming the file mapping, is to open it by name in the worker via `mmap.mmap(-1, size, shm_tag, mmap.ACCESS_READ)`. You need the exact `size` in this case because WinAPI `CreateFileMappingW` requires a source if the size is passed as 0, which the system uses to query the actual size. This is a limitation of the mmap module. In the Windows C API, you'd call `OpenFileMappingW` and then `MapViewOfFile` with `dwNumberOfBytesToMap = 0`.

Comment: BTW, you need a unique, instanced name such as `f'appname_shm_mmap_{os.getpid()}'` because all standard processes (not sandboxed) in the current session share the same local namespace for named kernel objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I've gotten it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eryk Sun's comments, I was able to make a working implementation:

```py
DATA = r"data.csv"

from sys import platform
if platform.startswith("win"):
    WINDOWS = True
    from msvcrt import get_osfhandle
else:
    WINDOWS = False
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
import mmap
from typing import Optional

def child(fd_or_size: int, shm_tag: Optional[str]) -> None:
    if WINDOWS:
        mm = mmap.mmap(-1, fd_or_size, shm_tag, mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    else:
        mm = mmap.mmap(fd_or_size, 0, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ)

    mm.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Open file
    fd = os.open(DATA, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_BINARY if WINDOWS else os.O_RDONLY)
    # Create memory map from file descriptor
    if WINDOWS:
        # Obtain underlying file handle from file descriptor
        os.set_handle_inheritable(get_osfhandle(fd), True)
        shm_tag = f"test_mmap_{os.getpid()}"
        mm = mmap.mmap(fd, 0, shm_tag, mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    else:
        os.set_inheritable(fd, True)
        mm = mmap.mmap(fd, 0, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ)

    # Run child process
    (p := Process(target = child, args = (mm.size() if WINDOWS else fd, shm_tag),
        daemon = True)).start()
    p.join()
    p.close()

    mm.close()
    os.close(fd)
```

Important changes (all on Windows):

- Use `get_osfhandle()` to obtain the underlying file handle from the file descriptor
- Give the memory map a tagname that's process-specific
- In the child process, attach to the memory map by giving the already-known size of the mapping.

Comment: You do not need `os.set_handle_inheritable(get_osfhandle(fd), True)` here. The current implementation depends on opening the file mapping by name in Windows. Moreover, remember that multiprocessing `Process` does not enable inheritance for spawned processes in Windows. It manually duplicates handles to child processes.